# Cómo hacer un UPDATE solo en un campo seleccionado del DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, webservice, soap

tengo que hacer una proyecto en la universidad con arquitectura SOAP, tengo un botón "Cambiar Estado" el cual llama un método que hace un **UPDATE** en la tabla "**pedidos_manga**" cambiando el "**estado_pedido**" de **Pendiente** a **Entregado**. Necesito que solo me haga el cambio el la fila seleccionada del dataGrid no en todos los campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Método para actualizar el Estado del Pedido**

```
  public void actualizarEstadoPedido(Pedidos_Manga pedidos)
    {         
            this.configurarConexion();
            this.Conex.NombreTabla = "pedidos_manga";
            this.Conex.CadenaSQL =   "UPDATE pedidos_manga SET estado_pedido = '" +
                                      pedidos.Estado_pedido+ "';";
            this.Conex.EsSelect = false;
            this.Conex.conectar();

    }
```

**WebService del Método anterior**

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void actualizarEstadoPedido(Pedidos_Manga pedidos)
    {
        NegocioPedidos auxEstadoPedido = new NegocioPedidos();
        auxEstadoPedido.actualizarEstadoPedido(pedidos);
    }
```

**Botón que llama al método**

```
  private void iconbtnCambiarEstadoPedido_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceStockManga.WebServiceStockSoapClient auxUpdatePedido = new ServiceStockManga.WebServiceStockSoapClient();
        ServiceStockManga.Pedidos_Manga auxUpdate = new ServiceStockManga.Pedidos_Manga();
        string value = "Entregado";
        if (dataGridViewPedidos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            auxUpdate.Estado_pedido = value;
            
            auxUpdatePedido.actualizarEstadoPedido(auxUpdate);

            MessageBox.Show("Datos actualizados correctamente");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saludos. Dentro de los datos con que llenas el DataGridView de la tabla `pedidos_manga` debes (asumo) traer el identificador (PK) con el que distingues inequívocamente cada registro; ese valor te hace falta asi como el `WHERE` en la parte **Método para actualizar el Estado del Pedido**. Desde luego ademas que no se observa que estado le pondras o si siempre será el mismo.

Comment: No tengo una (PK) dentro de esta tabla porque los datos de  `pedidos_manga ` los saco desde otra tabla llamada  `manga `, y para lo del  `id_user ` , guardo en un **string** el nombre que se uso en la textBox del Login y luego la inserto en la tabla  `pedidos_manga `.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Es necesario algún elemento (por ejemplo la `PK`) o conjunto de elementos (por lo regular dos o mas `FK`) por el que puedas hacer referencia a un registro en particular; de lo contrario estarás afectando más de un registro o (lo que es peor) todos los datos en la tabla. Bueno de la forma que yo trabajo, será cuestión des vistazo a tu estructura a fin de identificar como aplicarlo.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, realmente no soy muy bueno en esto de c# lo admito, lo que hice fue crear un método que me generara un código aleatorio, y este código lo inserto en el registro `id_pedido`, y ahora si hago uso del WHERE dentro del primer método. Como es un proyecto pequeño no espero generar una gran cantidad de datos.

Comment: si generaste un codigo unico para cada fila, esa es tu clave. Lo que te preguntaron fue cual es tu identificador unico de fila. O sea, como sabes que fila apreto? como la identificas mas alla de la grilla o lo que sea? eso es lo que tiene que recibir tu webservice ademas del dato a modificar...

Comment: la fila seleccionada en el dataGridView es la que se actualiza al seleccionarla y darle al botón, el problema que tenia era que al tener múltiples pedidos de un mismo usuario, se actualizaban todos a la vez. Pero ahora que agregue una (PK) a la tabla, y le puse una condición a la consulta ya no tengo este error.